# ¿Cómo activar una función cuando le de click a un elemento de un array?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un array, es este:

```
marks = [auto, casa, pc, tablet];
```

Ese array lo tengo en la vista a través de imágenes, entonces lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que cuando le doy click a algún elemento del array entonces se ejecute esta función

```
function marcadores(e){
    $('#modal'+marks[(aquí iría la posición del elemento seleccionado)]).modal("show");
   }
```

el problema que tengo es que no se cómo hacer para que cuando se le de click al elemento pueda mandar la posición de ese elemento a la función.

no puedo hacerlo con un ciclo for porque entonces solo se tendría en cuenta el ultimo elemento.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "lo tengo a la vista a través de imágenes? ¿Podrías poner un pantallazo y tu HTML?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Añade el código y dónde tienes el problema. En el evento onclick del elemento puedes recoger el id con this.id.

Comment: no le puedes dar clic a elementos de un arreglo, los eventos "click" se asocian a elementos html (`div - button - img - a`, etc). Tu dices "ese array lo tengo a la vista a través de imágenes", simplemente no puedo imaginarme a que te refieres con eso, el nombre del arreglo tampoco me dice mucho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo haber entendido tu pregunta y lo que vos queres hacer es obtener el posición del elemento en el array.
Te muestro un ejemplo de como lo haría yo:

```js
var listado = document.querySelectorAll('.listado');

for(var i = 0; i<listado.length;i++){
  listado[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {  
    console.log('Item numero ' + Array.from(listado).indexOf(e.target) + ' del array');
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="listado">Auto</li>
  <li class="listado">Casa</li>
  <li class="listado">PC</li>
  <li class="listado">Tablet</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero haber respondido tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayuda bastante!

Comment: Hola, una pregunta? se puede ademas imprimir el contenido de lo que he presionado, es decir cuando le de a "casa" ademas de aparecer la posición del array,  es posible que también se pueda imprimir "casa"?

Comment: ok ya lo logre hacer, muchas gracias!

Comment: Buenísimo!
No se como lo hiciste, en el caso de mi ejemplo lo haría con `e.target.innerText`